# SQL increment id, filling first line of database

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I habe a sqlite database in java (eclipse) with the library `sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar`.

I have 5 rows in table1: id(ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT), name, row3, row4, row5

I want to insert name, row3 and row4 and the id to increment itself.

```
public static void insertTest(String name, byte[] contentRow3, byte[] contentRow4) {

          String sql = "INSERT INTO table1(name, contentRow3, contentRow4) VALUES(?,?,?)";

            try (Connection conn = connect();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                pstmt.setString(2, name);
                pstmt.setBytes(3, contentRow3);
                pstmt.setBytes(4, contentRow4);
                System.out.println("Added new Person to DB");
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholders in Java prepared statements begin at index 1, not 2.  I expect that the following corrected code should work:

```
try (Connection conn = connect();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, name);
    pstmt.setBytes(2, contentRow3);
    pstmt.setBytes(3, contentRow4);
    System.out.println("Added new Person to DB");
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The exception you are getting is complaining that index position 3 is out of bounds.  Most likely, under the hood when you did `pstmt.setBytes(3, contentRow4)` this translated to accessing the *fourth* array element, which would be index 3 assuming the array indexing is zero based.

Comment: so the numer after setString ist not the row number?

Comment: The values you set on the `PreparedStatement` correspond to the question mark placeholders in your SQL query.  The indexing begins at 1, and since you have 3 question marks, therefore you should be setting 1, 2, and 3.